# itertools.chain.from_iterable works on nested numeric list but not string list?

Tags: python, pandas, iterable

I have a column in my data frame consists of lists, I would like to combine all the list from each row to just one single list in one cell.

This is what the column looks like

```
df.terms.dropna()
0     [Algorithms, Brain, Brain Mapping, Computer Si...
4     [Adult, Algorithms, Cerebrovascular Circulatio...
5     [Algorithms, Brain, Brain Mapping, Hemodynamic...
7     [Adult, Algorithms, Brain, Cerebrovascular Cir...
10    [Animals, Base Composition, Birds, Genetic Var...
Name: mesh_terms, dtype: object
```

I managed to combine them together and got

```
0    [[Algorithms, Brain, Brain Mapping, Computer S...],[Adult, Algorithms, Cerebrovascular Circulatio...],[Algorithms, Brain, Brain Mapping, Hemodynamic...],[list_index_7],[list_index_10]]
Name: mesh_terms, dtype: object
```

But I want a long list containing all strings like `[Algorithms, Brain, Brain Mapping, Computer Si..., ... , Animals, Base Composition, Birds, Genetic Var...]`

I've tried using itertools, but it still gave me a nested list, but it works on this example

```
list2d = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list2d))

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Also tried `flattened = [val for sublist in list_of_lists for val in sublist]` didn't get it to work either.

PLEASE HELP!

Here's a complete list of all the sublists

```
['Algorithms', 'Brain', 'Brain Mapping', 'Computer Simulation', 'Hemodynamics', 'Humans', 'Linear Models', 'Magnetic Resonance Imaging', 'Models, Neurological'] ['Adult', 'Algorithms', 'Cerebrovascular Circulation', 'Computer Simulation', 'Female', 'Functional Laterality', 'Globus Pallidus', 'Humans', 'Image Processing, Computer-Assisted', 'Magnetic Resonance Imaging', 'Male', 'Models, Neurological', 'Nonlinear Dynamics', 'Reinforcement (Psychology)', 'Reward', 'Young Adult'] ['Algorithms', 'Brain', 'Brain Mapping', 'Hemodynamics', 'Humans', 'Image Interpretation, Computer-Assisted', 'Linear Models', 'Magnetic Resonance Imaging', 'Models, Neurological'] ['Adult', 'Algorithms', 'Brain', 'Cerebrovascular Circulation', 'Female', 'Hemodynamics', 'Humans', 'Image Interpretation, Computer-Assisted', 'Magnetic Resonance Imaging', 'Male', 'Statistics, Nonparametric', 'Young Adult'] ['Animals', 'Base Composition', 'Birds', 'Genetic Variation', 'Genome', 'Genomics', 'Mammals', 'Molecular Sequence Data', 'Phylogeny', 'Reptiles', 'Retroelements', 'Tandem Repeat Sequences']
```

Comment: What did you do to combine them into a list of lists?

Comment: Try `[val for sublist in list_of_lists[0] for val in sublist]`, assuming list_of_lists is the object holding mesh_terms.

Comment: For me working nice - `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df['terms']))`

Comment: @BilltheLizard ```df_mesh = df['mesh_terms'].dropna() df_mesh.index = len(df_mesh)*[0] df_mesh = df_mesh.groupby(df_mesh.index).agg(list)``` I'm sure there are better ways to do it though!

Comment: @DanielMesejo that does put everything in one list, but not on the same line, which will create problem if I try to create a dataframe I believe.

Comment: I meant after you managed to combine them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to lists and then to `DataFrame` or `Series` constructor:

```
df_mesh = pd.DataFrame({'terms': [['Algorithms','Brain'],['Adult','Algorithms']]})
print (df_mesh)
                 terms
0  [Algorithms, Brain]
1  [Adult, Algorithms]

df = pd.DataFrame({'new': [df_mesh['terms'].tolist()]})
print (df)
                                          new
0  [[Algorithms, Brain], [Adult, Algorithms]]
```

---

```
s = pd.Series([df_mesh['terms'].tolist()])
print (s)
0    [[Algorithms, Brain], [Adult, Algorithms]]
dtype: object
```

Edit:

```
s1 = pd.Series([[val for sublist in df_mesh['terms'] for val in sublist]])
print (s1)
0    [Algorithms, Brain, Adult, Algorithms]
dtype: object
```

Or:

```
s1 = pd.Series([list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df_mesh['terms']))])
```

Comment: how does this change anything? looks like it's still a nested list

Comment: @Timxymo1225 - What is expcted output from my sample data?

Comment: ```print(s)``` will give you ```0    [[Algorithms, Brain], [Adult, Algorithms]]``` but what I'm looking for is ```[Algorithms, Brain, Adult, Algorithms]```

Comment: you, sir, are a freaking genius!